# CodeIgniter - escaping SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm trying to do an update to my database. One of the column values contains apostrophes, etc.  I have used `$this->db->escape` in CodeIgniter around the strings that may contain such characters, but I still get the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'O\'Keeffe, O\'Keefe'' WHERE `survey_id` = 188' at line 1

UPDATE `survey` SET `firstname_confidence_score` = 100, `firstname_rhymes` = '''', `lastname_confidence_score` = 85, `lastname_rhymes` = ''O\'Keeffe, O\'Keefe'' WHERE `survey_id` = 188;
```

How do I fix this?

UPDATE:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `$table_name` SET `firstname_confidence_score` = $firstname_confidence_score, `firstname_rhymes` = '" . $this->db->escape($firstname_rhymes) . "', `lastname_confidence_score` = $lastname_confidence_score, `lastname_rhymes` =  '" . $this->db->escape($lastname_rhymes) . "' WHERE `$primary_id` = $id;";
$result = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: It shouldn't be doubling up the quotes like that .. how are you using `escape`?

Comment: Are you using active record?  Can you post the code snippet that is creating your SQL statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `$this->db->escape()`, you are automatically adding single quotes around the data.

You query simply needs to be:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE `$table_name` 
         SET `firstname_confidence_score` = $firstname_confidence_score,  
             `firstname_rhymes` = " . $this->db->escape($firstname_rhymes) . ",  
             `lastname_confidence_score` = $lastname_confidence_score, 
             `lastname_rhymes` =  " . $this->db->escape($lastname_rhymes) . 
        "WHERE `$primary_id` = $id;";
```

You do not need the single quotes around `$this->db->escape($firstname_rhymes)` and so on.

Comment: Yup, that did it. The single quote surrounding the strings were from an earlier version of the SQL prior to me using $this->db->escape. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help, you just need an extra pair of eyes.  All the best!

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE `survey` SET `firstname_confidence_score` = 100, `firstname_rhymes` = '''', `lastname_confidence_score` = 85, `lastname_rhymes` = 'O\'Keeffe, O\'Keefe' WHERE `survey_id` = 188;
```

You had double apostraphes around the lastname_rhymes value.

Comment: You mean here: `'O\'Keeffe, O\'Keefe'`? I don't see double.